# Как изменить точку расчета градиента в tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

К примеру возьмем простую функцию `a**2 * x`, изначально `a` имеет значение 20:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32)
a = tf.Variable(20, dtype=tf.float32)
fn = tf.multiply(tf.square(a), x)
grad = tf.gradients(fn, a)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess.run(grad)
```

В примере выше вычислен градиент `fn` по `a` в точке 20. Нужно изменить точку вычисления градиента, как взять градиент этой функции по `a` в точке 25 а не 20 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то для формулы: [image: foo+bar]

где `x` - переменная, а `c` - константа:

```
c = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='x')
fn = tf.multiply(tf.square(x), c)
grad = tf.gradients(fn, [x])[0]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

sess.run(grad, feed_dict={x: 25})
```

результат:

```
500.0
```

Comment: Не много не то, но я не знал, что можно взять производную по  placeholder, это все решило, спасибо! Все проекты на pytorch пишу, после него tensorflow это просто кошмар, черт ногу сломит.

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, я тоже подумываю начать изучать PyTorch - как вам он? Он похож на Keras?

Comment: На Keras местами разве что, он лишен всех недостатков tensorflow, не нужно строить 10-и этажные графы, создавать сессии для компиляции, не нужно добавлять всякого рода операции в граф по типу как в с пакетной нормализацией в tf, все вычисления проводятся на месте и сразу, гибкость и простота просто потрясают, единственное что он сыроват немного еще, но это не мешает реализации проектов любой сложности, буду дома дам ссылку на хорошую книгу

Comment: С Keras ее вообще тяжело сравнивать (хотя есть схожие методы по построению модели) так как Keras высокоуровневая библиотека, а pytorch низкоуровневая, но если сравнить с tensorflow то небо и земля

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, спасибо за описание! Буду благодарен за ссылку на книгу

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/deep-learning-pytorch?utm_source=github&utm_medium=repository&utm_campaign=9781788624336 вот эта книга (довольно развернуто подан материал), только странно ее выпилили из всех обменников, где она не так давно лежала в свободном доступе, я бесплатно ее скачивал, полные примеры кода на ее странице https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, спасибо!!!